# Rails Turbolinks does not render response from submitted form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Submitting a basic xhr-form in a turbolinks-activated rails project (5.1), does trigger the correct server-side response but the client (turbolinks) discards the response. Neither get nor post do work. Tested in Firefox and Chromium. Forms with redirection work as intended.
    Here's a simple test page that fails for me

test.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @value %></h1>

<%= form_with url: 'test' do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :anything %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
      def test
    if request.post?
      @value = 'post'
    else
      @value = 'get'
    end
  end
```

routes:

```
 post '/test', to: 'controller#test'
  get '/test', to: 'controller#test'
```

rails response payload:

```
            <h1>post</h1>

<form action="test" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="X1sh+tc/Jx4P0rdDqc2CD1RetKQKr+lVh4fD29JOMY/b+PdPNgw1qyzoyv6t3I2I+6jV1mmn6voXN+YySaUISw==" />
  <input name="anything" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="anything" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="submit" data-disable-with="submit" />
</form>
        </div>
```

The form loads like expected, but after submitting the page does not change. Inside the xhr-response the correct answer is visible, but it does not get applied to the DOM.

Is this a bug, or am I using turbolinks wrong?

Comment: In case of xhr request, the file that is rendered is "*.js.erb". So, move your response in a new file "test.js.erb".

Comment: You will have to modify the DOM using javascript in that file.

Comment: Is there no other way? What I liked most about turbolinks is that I don't have to write (much) JS and it still stays a single page app (useful for websockets)

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this as well and I'm not sure how to proceed. What is nice about Turbolinks is that you don't have to create js responses for each request. This is true until you submit a form. At that point, you have no choice but to create a `js.erb` respone file or change the form to `local: true`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data: { turbolinks: false }` in the any links to the page containing the form.

E.g.

`<%= link_to "Get in Touch", 'contact', data: { turbolinks: false } %>`